# Load static data to Ext.data.TreeStore

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Can I load some static data to `Ext.data.TreeStore` instance?
It is pretty straightforward for Ext.data.Store - all we have to do - is to add [data param](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-data) to config.

But I can not see such thing for [Ext.data.TreeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create the TreeStore instance with a memory proxy, and then set the ROOT NODE of the store to the static data that you've got.

```
Ext.define('Task', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'task', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'user', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Task',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory'
    },
    folderSort: true
});

var data = {
    "text":".",
    "children": 
        [
            {
                task:'Project: Shopping', 
                user:'Will', 
                iconCls:'task-folder', 
                expanded: true,
                children:
                [
                    {
                        task:'Housewares', 
                        user:'Will', 
                        iconCls:'task-folder',
                        expanded: true,
                        children:[
                            { 
                                task:'Kitchen supplies', 
                                user:'Alpha', 
                                leaf:true, 
                                iconCls:'task' 
                            },
                            { 
                                task:'Groceries', 
                                user:'Bravo', 
                                leaf:true, 
                                iconCls:'task' 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

var rootNode = store.setRootNode(data);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also do:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: tree_model,
    // normally the data object would go here
    proxy: {
        data : data, // instead it goes here
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is [root](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-cfg-root) instead of `data` in TreeStore.